# Get equal values within a stack

Tags: java, data-structures, stack

I'm doing a stack on java that this contains five integers but I have to print out only the values are equal.

Example 1 - 2 - 2 - 3 - 4
The same number is: 2

**How can I determine which make the same numbers?**

Here is my code:

```
package e.d_pilas;

import java.util.*;

public class ED_PILAS {
    private int stck[];
    private int tos;

    ED_PILAS(int size){
        //New stack
        stck = new int[size];
        tos = -1;
    }

    void push(int value) {
        stck[++tos] = value;
    }

    int pop() {
        if (tos < 0) {
            return 0;
        } else
            return stck[tos--];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number;
        Scanner read = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter five (5) numbers to fill the stack \n");
        ED_PILAS stack = new ED_PILAS(5);

        for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++){
            System.out.print("Enter the value "+i+" to fill the stack \n");
            number=read.nextInt();
            stack.push(number); 
        }
        System.out.println("Equal values contained in the stack: \n");

        for (int j = 1; j < 6; j++){
            System.out.println("\t " + stack.pop());    
        } 
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: what if there are more than one same numbers?

Comment: @SarthakMittal also display as long as they are more than two

Comment: is it really necessary to use Stack?

Comment: @SarthakMittal yes, it's part of the job

Comment: since you already got working answers posted, using stack for these type of problems is very inefficient :)

Comment: @SarthakMittal the use of a stack for this kind of problems is inefficient but at the end is an interactive exercise, try new things is fun. Thank you!

Comment: don't thank me, i did nothing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first method it will print the duplicates entries only one time. in second method if stack contains more than two entries it will print multiple times.

```
        ArrayList<int> list=new ArrayList<int>();

        for (int j = 1; j < 6; j++){
            int num=stack.pop();
            if(list.contains(num)){
               System.out.println(num);
            }
            else{
                 list.add(num);
            }

        }
```

**OR**
`stack.pop()` methods removes the element then use `stack.search()` method to find duplicates

```
            for (int j = 1; j < 6; j++){
             int num=stack.pop();
             if(stack.search(num)==1){
               System.out.println(num);
            }
            else{

            }

        }
```

Comment: the method has been the most logical and simple to implement.

Answer (score 0):

While you do `pop()` from stack you can store in `ArrayList<Integer>` and check on every `pop()` if it already exists or not. If it repeats then print it and mark it as printed (so that you donot print it again).

Answer (score 0):

Use this logic it will work for consecutive same values otherwise use ArrayList:

`int n=stack.pop();
    int dummy;
    for (int j = 1; j < 6; j++){
    dummy=stack.pop();
    if(n==dummy)
    {
    System.out.println("\t The same number is " + n);
    }
    else{
    n=dummy;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Use an ArrayList to store the previous  pop'd values. If you see this value again during a pop, simply print the number.

```
ArrayList<Integer> popdList=new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (int j = 1; j < 6; j++){
    int value=stack.pop();
    if(popdList.contains(value){
        System.out.println(value);
     } else{
         popdList.add(value);
     }
}
```

[More info on ArrayLists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Also, instead of changing your main function you could edit your pop function to only return the duplicate values like this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> popdList=new ArrayList<Integer>();

int pop() {
    if (tos < 0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        int value = stck[tos--];
        if(popdList.contains(value){
            return value;
        } else{
            popdList.add(value);
        }
    }
}
```